# Change printername in PrintDialog through code

Tags: .net, printing, printdialog

I am attempting to change the selected printer of my PrintDialog through code. I am creating an image that needs to be printed, but the size of the image determines which printer should be used. I have the name of the printer that I want to use but I just can't figure out where to change that value. Any help can be in either VB.NET or C#.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should look for the [**PrinterName Property**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.printername.aspx). This property resides in the [**PrinterSettings Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printersettings.aspx). The PrinterSettings class is also a [**property of the PrintDialog**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printdialog.printersettings.aspx). This way you can access the PrinterSettings and change the PrinterName-property.

```
//Example for GETTING the printername
var pd = new PrintDialog();
var settings = pd.PrinterSettings;
var name = settings.PrinterName

//Example for SETTING the printername
var pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = "YOUR_PRINTER_NAME";
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to find. Thank you.